# how to show data in CSV in different colums using plsql?

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, oracle11g, toad

I have written sql to generate the output data in CSV format.I have used spool to generate in CSV.

```
SET LINESIZE 1000 TRIMSPOOL ON FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL E:\oracle\extract\emp2.csv

  SELECT emp_id,
           emp_name

    FROM   offc.employee
    ORDER BY emp_id;

SPOOL OFF

SET PAGESIZE 14
```

The output is coming in location.The output is generated correctly but when I see the CSV file ,then all the data are coming in `same column A` in CSV.

[image]

I want `emp_id in column A` and `emp_name in columnB`.Why they are coming in same column? What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the issue is the space is considered as the `separator` for your column data and excel can not separate the column values which are `space separated`.

You can use `colsep` attribute along with other attributes as following:

```
set colsep , -- defines column data separator
set pagesize 14 -- defines size of the page. Keep it large so that header is not repeated
set trimspool on -- remove trailing blanks
set lines 1000 -- linesize should be more than sum of width of the all columns
set FEEDBACK OFF -- removes the comment at the end of the data

SPOOL E:\oracle\extract\emp2.csv

  SELECT emp_id,
           emp_name

    FROM   offc.employee
    ORDER BY emp_id;

SPOOL OFF
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

> What is the problem here?

Excel expects a Comma Separated Values file to have values in columns separated by commas. Your query outputs two columns of data but doesn't include an explicit separator. So when Excel reads the file it doesn't find any commas so it renders a single column of data.

There are various ways of solving this. One is include your own explicit separator in the query:

```
SELECT emp_id
      || ', ' ||
      emp_name
FROM   offc.employee
ORDER BY emp_id;
```

Another is to use [the SQL*Plus `colsep` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm) to format the output in the file. A third option is to use a tool like SQL Developer, whose Export feature handles all this for us.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about my own experience: although Excel *knows* how to open a `CSV` file, it is kind of *stupid* and still puts everything into the first column. Therefore, I prefer creating a `TXT` file instead, using a column separator (so - yes, it basically *is* a comma-separated-file (or whichever separator you choose)).

For example:

```
SQL> set pagesize 100
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> set colsep ";"
SQL>
SQL> spool emp.txt
SQL>
SQL> select * from emp;

     EMPNO;ENAME     ;JOB      ;       MGR;HIREDATE;       SAL;      COMM;    DEPTNO
----------;----------;---------;----------;--------;----------;----------;----------
      7369;SMITH     ;CLERK    ;      7902;17.12.80;       800;          ;        20
      7499;ALLEN     ;SALESMAN ;      7698;20.02.81;      1600;       300;        30
      7521;WARD      ;SALESMAN ;      7698;22.02.81;      1250;       500;        30
      7566;JONES     ;MANAGER  ;      7839;02.04.81;      2975;          ;        20
      7654;MARTIN    ;SALESMAN ;      7698;28.09.81;      1250;      1400;        30
      7698;BLAKE     ;MANAGER  ;      7839;01.05.81;      2850;          ;        30
      7782;CLARK     ;MANAGER  ;      7839;09.06.81;      2450;          ;        10
      7788;SCOTT     ;ANALYST  ;      7566;09.12.82;      3000;          ;        20
      7839;KING      ;PRESIDENT;          ;17.11.81;      5000;          ;        10
      7844;TURNER    ;SALESMAN ;      7698;08.09.81;      1500;         0;        30
      7876;ADAMS     ;CLERK    ;      7788;12.01.83;      1100;          ;        20
      7900;JAMES     ;CLERK    ;      7698;03.12.81;       950;          ;        30
      7902;FORD      ;ANALYST  ;      7566;03.12.81;      3000;          ;        20
      7934;MILLER    ;CLERK    ;      7782;23.01.82;      1300;          ;        10

14 rows selected.

SQL> spool off;
```

Now, start Excel and go to **Open**; choose "All files" (i.e. not only Excel-type files) so that you'd see `emp.txt` listed. Excel then - in its "Text Import Wizard" - asks you which kind of a file it is (choose **delimited**):

[image]

set the separator (**semi-colon** in our example)

[image]

and - open the file:

[image]

Everything is now in its own column.

Comment: If your CSV (comma-separated values) file has columns separated by **commas** Excel will process it just fine. If you use semicolons or vertical bars or tabs or other characters which are **not commas** Excel needs some help as you've noted.